# How to get maximum number of tweets on an user

Tags: api, twitter

i have this code

```
("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser.'&count=500'
```

But it is giving me only 200 records , I found in twitter document that it will give 3200 tweets.Is i am doing wrong what should i do to get that much tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no page system in twitter 's API, to go throught timelines, you must use the "max_id" parameter.

Here is an helpful link that explains how to work with timelines with nice illustrations: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines.

Edit: here is how you do it.

"To use max_id correctly, an application’s first request to a timeline endpoint should only specify a count."

Make your request "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser.'&count=500  (you can put 200).

Then when you get all your data, " keep track of the lowest ID received" and use it as parameter (the same way you do for the count) for your next request. it will give you the 200 next posts with a lower id than the one you specified. Do it again until you reach the end.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline i found this link but i am not understanding how i use it . How i get tha max _id or since_id.

Comment: I am still not getting it which lowest id this type of info i am getting  [created_at] => Wed Nov 11 10:35:14 +0000 2015
            [id] => 6.6439092263374E+17
            [id_str] => 664390922633740290 etc.

Comment: then pick the lowest id_str of all the 200 post you get  and build your new request  (id_str = id  to string format, because the basic id is very long to be stored in an int)